# Find the block class instantiated into a phtml file

Tags: magento-2.1, php, theme, phtml, html

I need to modify a block class called in a phtml file, this is the `customer.phtml` file:

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if($block->customerLoggedIn()): ?>
    <li class="customer-welcome">
        <span class="customer-name"
              role="link"
              tabindex="0"
              data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
              data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname"></span>
            <button type="button"
                    class="action switch"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    data-action="customer-menu-toggle">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change')?></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "customer": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
        <?php if($block->getChildHtml()):?>
       <div class="customer-menu" data-target="dropdown">
            <?php echo **$block->getChildHtml()**;?>
       </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm interested in the block beetween the `div` with class `customer-menu`.
I want to remove `<ul class="header link">` tag but not their `li` children, this `ul` tag is inside the `<ul class="header link">` when someone is logged in.

Comment: Can you specify what actually you want to remove?

Comment: You want to remove the ul class based on customer login/logout action?

Comment: The ul tag when a customer is logged in, when it is not logged in the block is not loaded. what is the class of $block->getChildHtml()?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the **Customer Block Class** in:

> Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer.php

Comment: There is no getChildHtml() method.

Comment: I think that method is a reserve magento method used to get child block of the parent block